# Проверка вхождения слова в List

Tags: java, junit

Проверить надо с помощью JUnit. Есть список слов, нужно проверить, есть ли в этом списке определенное слово или нет. А лучше проверить, содержат ли слова с списке определенную строку. Например слово "слово" содержит в себе "лов"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно пробежаться по списку `list` и проверить наличие вхождения подстроки `word`:

```
assertTrue(list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains(word)));
```

Так будет проверено, что хотя бы одна строка в списке содержит указанную подстроку. Если нужно проверить, чтобы в каждой строке было вхождение - вместо `anyMatch` нужно будет использовать `allMatch`.